# Keep getting the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allauth'. I tried all the steps in the similar question, but to no avail

Tags: django, django-allauth

I installed allauth through pip install django-allauth and I keep getting an error. I uninstalled it and installed it again with
pip install django-rest-auth[with_social]. Still getting the same error. Here's traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allauth'
```

Comment: Did you add it on settings?

Comment: Yes, I did. All steps as per https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: type this command [pip freeze] in your env and check if its installed.